# php - how replace cid to link for php email?

Tags: php, imap

how can replace the cid image for each image name from the email
this my code

```
$input  = $obj->getBody($from);
$output2 = preg_replace("/cid:(.*?)@[\w.]*/","http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/cchelp/attach/".$value."", $input);
echo $output2;
```

thank you for your help

Comment: What does this do currently? What is `$input`?

Comment: what results are you getting now, and what results are you looking to get?

Comment: it is to get email body from the email i get the inline image as attachment and it is save to the folder now i want display that image on the email but the image src is cid not link and this code it to replace the cid to link but it is replace on image to all cid now the issue the are multi inline image with different name so i want to match the image name on the email cid and replace it with the correct image what it is downlod it to the folder

Comment: The issue is probably that `$value` isn't set anywhere I see. Is that suppose to be the grouped value from the regex?

Comment: dear @chris85 the value is multi image name and it is set and i get the result for all inline image but the issue when the preg_replace run is take one image only and replace it to all cid now i want to get the image name from the cid and match it with the $value to run the preg_replace for the current image cid .. thank you for your help

Comment: Can your provide a) what you have and b) what you want? I'm not sure I'm following what you are asking.

Comment: @chris85 dear the $input it is HTML email and in that email have inline image and is encoding as cid I try to get that email by use IMAP and I get it normly but the image is not showing whan I display the email so I have to downlod the image and it is saved normally to attachment folder so I try to replace the link of the image what is as cod to normal link so now by use my code it is replace one image to all cid on the HTML email so now I want to get the name of the image what is on cid and match it and replace it to same name what's dowloded on the attach folder

Comment: @chris85 for example if there is cid : image001.jpg@something I want to get the cid:image001.ipg@something and replace it to http://127.0.0.1/cchelp/attach/image001.jpg and for cid:image002.jpg@somthing replace it to http://127.0.0.1/attach/image002.jpg

Comment: Then yes see my comment #2. Replace value should be `"http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/cchelp/attach/$1"`

Comment: @chris85 I don't think so I think there is way to but the cid as array than and match it with the $value .. I have the solution but I don't know how I but it as code

Comment: Can you phrase that differently? Where is there an array? What is `$value`, in example 1 above shouldn't it be `image001.ipg` ? You're not doing anything with the value you find in the regex currently.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok with your code, just check if the cid argument has "@" because sometimes it doesn't (like cid:useratexample.com) and your regex needs this to work properly